# Twitter share with SLRequest

Tags: ios

This is Sam.Currently I am devloping twitter share in my application.I need to implement that without ComposeController.I need to integrate with SLRequest from social framework.
The Code which i using is as below as

```
ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
ACAccountType *twitterAccountType =[accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];
[accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:twitterAccountType options:NULL completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
    if (granted) {
        NSLog(@"Creating Request");
        //  Step 2:  Create a request
        NSArray *twitterAccounts =[accountStore accountsWithAccountType:twitterAccountType];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.0/statuses/update.json"];
        NSDictionary *params = @{@"screen_name" : @"naheshsamy",@"include_rts" : @"0",@"trim_user" : @"1",@"count" : @"1"};
        SLRequest *request =
        [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET URL:url parameters:params];

        //  Attach an account to the request
        [request setAccount:[twitterAccounts lastObject]];
        NSLog(@"Request %@",request);
        //  Step 3:  Execute the request
        [request performRequestWithHandler: ^(NSData *responseData,NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse,NSError *error) {
            if (responseData) {
                if (urlResponse.statusCode >= 200 && urlResponse.statusCode < 300) {
                    NSError *jsonError;
                    NSDictionary *timelineData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&jsonError];

                    if (timelineData) {
                        NSLog(@"Timeline Response: %@\n", timelineData);
                    }
                    else {
                        // Our JSON deserialization went awry
                        NSLog(@"JSON Error: %@", [jsonError localizedDescription]);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    // The server did not respond ... were we rate-limited?
                    NSLog(@"The response status code is %d %@ %@",urlResponse.statusCode,urlResponse.suggestedFilename,error);
                }
            }
        }];
    }
    else {
        // Access was not granted, or an error occurred
        NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}];
```

I am always getting status 400 error..
Any help will be appreciated.
Regards,
Sam.P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code seems similar to what I have used.
They do have warned that version 1.0 of the API is no longer supported and may not function. Try changing to 1.1 and see if it solves your problem.

```
@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json"
```

Comment: thanks for your valuable answer lira..Now i have get success share with twitter API's.Now i need to know how share with access token without using default twitter account..